# Textarea self closing tag? <textarea />

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I recently watched some tutorials on youtube about building a simple react markdown previewer for a Freecodecamp challenge. However, the tutorials I've seen so far added this tag `<textarea />` in the react code instead of `<textarea></textarea>`.

I looked up more info about `<textarea>` tag and w3schools, mdn web docs, and few other web sites still showed the `<textarea>` with its closing tag `</textarea>` with the reason that it acts as a container for the stuff inside the `<textarea>` tag. And to use it in different form would break the code.

Anyway, I'm wondering if it's still necessary in React framework to use the self-closing method such as this: `<textarea />`? I'm just trying to figure out if I need to use `<textarea />` in my project I'm coding or whether it's bad coding/practice.

Comment: The HTML specs dictate which tags may omit their closing (or opening) tag. The `textarea` is not one of them according to the MDN docs. See the *Technical summary*. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#Technical_summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, textarea has been modified so it can behave like other inputs.  The value, which would normally be a child in HTML is an attribute in React

```
<textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

See the [React Docs for more info on textarea](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-textarea-tag)

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried to find that in React Docs but I might have overlooked it. Thanks for pointing it out for me!

Answer (score 1):

For React, it's mostly a convention.
One convention is to always use self-closing tags if there is no content ( children) inside of your component. So for a textarea it would be self closing.

Answer (score 1):

It's not HTML in React. It is JSX. If you don't have children in a element, just use self close tag. If you have children in element, then use separate close tag.

You can see how it convert HTML to JSX using this web site - https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm